# How to disable input fields conditionally in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
 <input
            :type="passwordFieldType"
            v-model="user.password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            class="input-section-three"
            :class="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && $v.user.password.$error }"
            placeholder="Enter new password"
            :maxlength="maxpassword"
            v-on:keypress="isPassword($event)"
          />
          
 <input
            :type="passwordFieldTypetwo"
            v-model="user.confirmPassword"
            id="confirmPassword"
            name="confirmPassword"
            class="input-section-three"
            :class="{
              'is-invalid': submitted && $v.user.confirmPassword.$error,
            }"
            placeholder="Confirm password"
             :maxlength="maxconfirmpassword"
            v-on:keypress="isconfirmPassword($event)"
            
          />
```

I have two input fields like password and confirm password. where i am trying to disable confirm password field, untill user enter some content in password field. Can we do anything with  v-bind:disabled="newPassword.length === 0 ? true : false" to get resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply need to lock the second field until the user types anything in the first one, try using the `disabled` attribute on the second input:

```
<input 
    :disabled="!user.password"
    ...
>
```

This will set the `disabled` attribute as long as the value of `user.password` is falsy (eg. empty string).

Comment: Its working fine. But what if i want to set like, If user enter 8 digits in the first field, then only second input to be enabled. So in this case any attributes do i need to pass to :disabled=' ....'

Comment: In that case, just change the condition to whatever you need (e.g. :disabled="user.password.length<8).
If the condition is any more complicated than that, you'll want to move it to a separate method in the component.

Answer (score 1):

You can set either the `:disabled="!newPassword"` or `:read-only="!newPassword"` properties on the field.

Either one should achieve the desired outcome, and then in your css if you need to apply any specific styles to the field you can use `#confirmPassword::disabled {}` or `#confirmPassword::read-only {}`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Its working fine. But what if i want to set like, If user enter 8 digits in the first field, then only second input to be enabled. So in this case any attributes do i need to pass to :disabled=' ....'

Comment: You can bind the value of `disabled` to any javascript variable or evaluation you like.  So if you want to instead of saying when newPassword is empty, you want to say when the length is bigger then 8 you'll just say `:disabled="newPassword.length >= 8"`